# Capistrano 3 recipe for dynamic_sitemaps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, capistrano3

I'm trying to "translate" the Capistrano recipe to deploy [dynamic_sitemaps](https://github.com/lassebunk/dynamic_sitemaps) to work with Capistrano 3.

The snippet suggested in the readme looks like this:

```
after "deploy:update_code", "sitemaps:create_symlink"

namespace :sitemaps do
  task :create_symlink, roles: :app do
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/sitemaps"
    run "rm -rf #{release_path}/public/sitemaps"
    run "ln -s #{shared_path}/sitemaps #{release_path}/public/sitemaps"
  end
end
```

But this doesn't work with Capistrano 3. I pasted this code into config/deploy.rb and the first error I got was: *Don't know how to build task 'sitemaps:create_symlink'`*.

I read somewhere that in Capistrano 3 the namespaces have to be defined before the calls so I reversed the order of the blocks, defining the `namespace` first and having the `after` call last. I got *NoMethodError: undefined method `map' for :roles:Symbol`*.

So I rewrote the namespace block to:

```
namespace :sitemaps do
  task :create_symlink do 
    on roles(:web) do
      run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/sitemaps"
      run "rm -rf #{release_path}/public/sitemaps"
      run "ln -s #{shared_path}/sitemaps #{release_path}/public/sitemaps"
    end
  end
end
```

And now I'm getting *Don't know how to build task 'deploy:update_code'* and I'm at loss.

Comment: where is this update_code is defined ? Is this your own method or task

Comment: apparently [`deploy:update_code`](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/Capistrano-Tasks#deployupdate_code) is a valid Capistrano task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I couldn't solve precisely the issue I posted above, the solution is actually very simple. If using Capistrano 3 just add `public/sitemaps` to your `:linked_dirs` setting as such:

`set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp vendor/bundle public/system public/sitemaps}`

This will create a symbolic link between `#{release_path}/public/sitemaps` and `#{shared_path}/public/sitemap` creating the latter if needed.